# Select input with id and name cakephp3

Tags: select, orm, cakephp-3.0

In my controller, make this filter

```
 $categories = $this->Posts->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->select(['id', 'category_name']);
```

And in my view

```
echo $this->Form->select('category_id', $categories->toArray());
```

But, the data returned in array is just the code(in this case id). How to implement a *select* with id and category_name? Should be do manually?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `select` in this case. Either use `displayField` to tell it you want the category_name, or specify the `keyField` and `valueField` parameters in the options to the `list` call, as per [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs).

```
$this->Posts->Categories->displayField('category_name');
$categories = $this->Posts->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
```

or

```
$categories = $this->Posts->Categories->find('list', [
    'limit' => 200,
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'categoryName'
]);
```